# Multiple Hasthag on Facebook Share Android

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I manage to create an app that can share picture along with the hasthag with this facebook sdk version 4.+.

In my app I have three checkbox that each contains the option of hasthag people want to share.

With the code i currently have

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                                .setBitmap(bitmap)
                                .build();
                        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                                .addPhoto(photo)
                                .setShareHashtag(new ShareHashtag.Builder()
                                        .setHashtag(hastag1).build())
                                .build();

                        ShareDialog.show(SelfieActivity.this,content);
```

Can only post one hasthag. I have tried setting the hasthag as

```
.setHashtag(hastag1+" "+hastag2+" "+hastag3)
```

Only post the first one.

Anybody knows how to post multiple hasthag?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: no haven't yet...I read that facebook only allowed one hastag with this sdk

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Facebook only allowed one hashtag